# Hadoop in pseudo-distributed Mode. Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, hadoop

P.S: Please do not mark this as duplicate

Hi,

I have been trying to set up and run Hadoop in the pseudo Distributed Mode. When I run the start-all.sh script I get this output:

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/raveesh/Hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/..
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/raveesh/Hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/..
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
raveesh@raveeshL:~/Hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin$
```

Here is what I have done. I have installed the open-ssh server and the client using:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

I have started the ssh server as in

```
sudo service ssh start
```

And I get the output as:

```
ssh start/running, process 5466
```

I have also run the following commands :

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa

cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But when I run the start-all script it still shows connection refused. I have also tried the tips mentioned [here](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html) but I am unable to get it to work. I am behind a firewall and I am using Ubuntu. Is there something that I am missing?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A possible answer is that /etc/ssh/ssh_config has not been correctly configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you install ssh, you should also enable password-less login.

```
% ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
% cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Additionally, you should check that `ssh localhost` works without prompting you for a password.

Comment: Hi , I have already run those commands.. I forgot to mention in the question.. Have modified the question.. Thanks for pointing out.. The issue still persists.. Is there anything w.r.t port that i should take care of.. or anything in the ssh_config file that I should take care of?

Comment: Hi Chris. ssh localhost  does not indicate anything at all. It simply stays at the prompt..

Comment: Are you sure the ssh deamon runs on localhost ? 
Do something like : pgrep sshd

Comment: Other stuff to check: Make sure ~/.ssh permissions are 700, /etc/sshd/sshd_config contains `RSAAuthentication yes` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes`, Check SELinux. Also, `ssh localhost -vvv` may give more hints as to what is going on.

Comment: Hi same problem here... Tried all the steps mentioned... But no luck