# Installing Hadoop in Pseudo Distributed Mode

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-partitioning

I'm newbie to Hadoop and today I'm trying to install pseudo distributed mode. Here is the link I follow: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm
Everything is fine until I run the command:

```
start-dfs.sh
```

Here is what printed out:

```
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
```

Please help me solve this. I tried many solutions on this site including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490429/hadoop-in-pseudo-distributed-mode-connection-refused) but no luck. Thanks

As required by comments below, here is content of hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode </value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
  <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode </value> 
</property>
</configuration>
```

And here is content of core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name </name>
  <value> hdfs://localhost:9000 </value> 
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide `hdfs-site.xml` and  `core-site.xml`

Comment: If you are newbie, you should try to do first a single node cluster.

Comment: @s.singh: I edited the question, please have a look

Comment: @chomp: I successfully tested single node cluster, but pseudo distributed processing doesn't work for me

Comment: If you are using hadoop newer version, try to replace `<name>fs.default.name </name>` with `<name>fs.defaultFS</name>`. If it now works try with `8020` port and check once again.

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry. I'm using version 2.7.0